# Joomla URL canonicalisation

Tags: url, seo, joomla

Could somebody suggest the best way to redirect the non-www to the www in Joomla? I would normally do this in the .htaccess file but I'm unsure if it's the best way to do it with dynamic websites.

Many thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension to achieve this, you can find it [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/5355) on the Joomla extension directory

Answer (score 0):

i would do this via the .htaccess file its the best way as then Google will just index your www.xxx site.